Are there any social platforms designed around reading and discussing books?
I have noticed that a book may be less enjoyable if, after reading it, you have nobody to share its contents with and make and discuss little plans around the book's content.
I wonder whether there are social networks where you can pick books from Google Play Books, arrange to read them, and make plans to meet up either on some video chat platform or in some physical room, in order to discuss the book and decide what the little plans around the book read must be.
The readers may also read more than one book with non-empty intersection among the readers' book reading list prior to meeting.
Are there any platforms that meet these requirements?

What do you mean by "make and discuss little plans around the book's content"? What sort of "plans" did you have in mind?

Try Reddit. There are several book- and reading-related subreddits there. Ask in them.
